# Why was everyone attempting to fool Ulla?

Tags: sunday-without-god

This contains spoilers for *Sunday Without God*.

**Ulla Euleus Hecmatika** is the princess of Ortus, the capital of death.

She is the Idol of Murder, and whoever she sees, talks to, or touches, dies. Supposedly, she doesn't know this, as she's been fooled her whole life.

**Kiriko**, her instructor, was asked by some elders/superiors/whatever to fool Ulla.

What were they **expecting to accomplish** by lying to her?

Not from Kiriko's point of view, but rather from the elders/superiors who asked him to do it. Why do they want to fool Ulla? What were they attempting to avoid had she known the truth?

I suppose that she could get rebellious if she knows that she's murdering newcomers who want to join Ortus, but the concept of death has blended too well into the world's culture for over 15 years, so it is a daily, trivial thing and I can't imagine the elders considering it a bad idea to explain it to Ulla.

Answer (score 1):

If the newcomers bring in new ideas about death, she might feel bad that she causes everyone to die. Like you said death has a very blended meaning. Since she is alive, she might get rebellious. I assume the elders wanted her to believe in what she was doing was 'okay' without having to deal with her wavering faith. Kiriko loved Ulla and spoiled her. 
Also remember living people still stay in the inns, so if a person unwillingly dies or always avoid her, it might change Ulla's meaning of 'death' and she won't kill anyone anymore. Ulla also is still alive, and in ep.6 it mentions the children of immigrants are still alive until the age of 15 so she might find it sad she can't go outside without killing people. In the end, they accomplished making her have a different meaning to the word "death", and for it to work they needed everyone around her to act a certain way.